# Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_diff()

Tags: php

i get the following error, "Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_diff()" on line 34

**Here is the code:**

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2015-05-18');
$datum = "2015-05-20";
$datetime2 = date_create('now');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$dagen = $interval->format('%R%a dagen');
    echo("
```

I have no idea what i am doing wrong, hopefully someone could help me.

Comment: what's your php version? `date_diff` is available only from 5.3

Comment: I think my webhost degraded the php version to 5.2. Is it possible in 5.2?

Comment: @JoeyFelling, 5.4 is the current stable, there are certainly workarounds, but it'd be best to consult with your host to get on a more relevant PHP version.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the fast replies. The problem is that all of my other files are made in 5.2 and most wont work 100% if upgraded. I would really like to know how to do this in 5.2.

Comment: Even 5.4 is security fixes only now - http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: but please, upgrade your php to a stable version... otherwise you shouldn't even pay your webhost

Comment: How is that? Thanks for the link btw. I am still relatively new to php.